# Apache commons-exec not able to run a mysql script file on command line

Tags: java, mysql, command-line, apache-commons, executor

I am trying to run a mysql command from java that takes input from an sql script file using apache commons-exec as shown below

```
    filepath = /path/to/file.sql
    CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("mysql -uuser -ppassword dbname");
    commandLine.addArgument("<");
    commandLine.addArgument(filepath);
    Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.execute(commandLine);
```

But I keep getting the following error

> [junit] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysql -uuser
>   -ppassword  dbname" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory

When I run on the terminal, 
the command executes normally and db gets modified. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Found a work around by creating a script file that runs mysql command in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CmdTool](https://github.com/alekseysotnikov/CmdTool) library.

```
    String filepath ="/path/to/file.sql";
    List<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("mysql", "-uuser", "-ppassword", "dbname"));
    commandLine.add("<");
    commandLine.add(filepath);
    new Cmd().command(commandLine).execute();
```

Or simpler

```
new Cmd().command("mysql", "-uuser", "-ppassword", "dbname", "<", filepath).execute();
```

You can find more examples [here](https://github.com/alekseysotnikov/CmdTool).